# Usage of atoi in c program

Tags: c, atoi

I have this code but here atoi does not work at all 
If i gave base address then also it causes prob

```
int main()
{
    char *token;
    int value;
    char data = "23+100";
    int i = 0;
    while(data[i] != '+' )
    {
        value = atoi(data[i]);
        push(value,&top1);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings.

Comment: How did that even compile? Or is that what you meant by it doesn't work?

Comment: read atoi's documentations first

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
char data = "23+100";
```

really shouldn't have compiled.

It should be:

```
const char *data = "23+100";
```

Which will make `atoi(data[i]);` even less correct than it was before.

Also, you're not supposed to use `atoi()` on sub-strings like that. Perhaps you should look at `sscanf()` or `strtok()`, or (perhaps best if I understand what you're after correctly) `strtol()`.

The latter allows you to parse a `long` integer until a non-digit character is found, and also lets you figure out which character that was after the call.

Comment: data[i] is not even a substring... it is a single char, a substring would be &data[i]... and it would be wrong in any case :)

Comment: jeklly 
You want me store first that single char and then pass to atoi?

Comment: The `strtol` function could be convienient here. It scans your string until the first non digit (+ in this case).

Comment: atoi shouldn't be used at all as it's not standard c, also I'd highly recommend against using scanf or any variant of that function.
Really you should be using snprintf

Comment: @wybourn `snprintf()` instead of `scanf()`?! What?

Comment: @wybourn: Totally agree with you up to the point you mentioned `snprintf()`. The proper function to use is `strtol()`, or `strtoul()`, as those allow proper error handling.

Answer (score 0):

array initialization is wrong it could be either

`char data[] = "23+100"`

or as unwind told

`const char *data = "23+100"`

and one more thing your logic for going through the array might be wrong.

As soon as `+` is encountered the loop is finished and `100 won't` be converted and push'd onto the stack(hoping your trying to achieve that)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `strtol` function. Following sample shows how to use it.

```
int main()
{
  char *token;
  int value;
  char *data = "23+100-2*7";
  int i = 0;
  char *endp ;
  token = data ;

  do
  {
    value = strtol(token, &endp, 10) ;
    token = endp + 1 ;
    printf ("value: %d\n", value) ;

    if (*endp != 0)
      printf ("operator: %c\n", *endp) ;

  } while (*endp != 0) ;
}
```